# PHP singleton not accessible

Tags: php, singleton

i've got a bit of a problem with getting a singleton to work in php 5.3

What i want to achieve is that i'll be able to include one php file with a class,
that lets me translate webpages by a dictionary over a global singleton.

Usage example:

```
<?php
    include_once "CLocale.php";
?>
//...
<head>
<title><?php CLocale::Instance()->getText("StrMemberArea")?></title>
```

My class looks like the following at the moment:

```
class CLocale
{
    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    public static function Instance()
    {
        if (static::$_instance === NULL)
        {
            static::$_instance = new static();
        }
        return static::$_instance;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function getText($str)
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

So, the problem is, i don't get any output of "Test" when using the class like shown above,
also, i don't get any error. PHP Storm isn't really showing me any errors.
Perhaps one of you guys is able to spot a problem somewhere.

*Thanks in advance,
calav3ra*

PS: I don't mind how the singleton is implemented

Comment: You're returning it. But you're not passing it to output, as there is no `echo` call.

Comment: Thanks, geremy/nslbshtr. I cannot believe what i did. And i wasted three hours before asking here. Thanks a lot, again! :)

Comment: Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to look into your code, to see something obvious:)

Comment: I know. Actually, i didn't sleep enough, but still feel ok - but it's always the same :)

Answer (score 3):

Yo forgot to echo the result

```
<title><?php CLocale::Instance()->getText("StrMemberArea")?></title>
```

should be:

```
<title><?php echo CLocale::Instance()->getText("StrMemberArea")?></title>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot PeterM, the same applies to your answer as to . I cannot believe what i did. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ehm - the Singleton code is completely right, but you forgot to output the return value from getText

```
<?php
    include_once "CLocale.php";
?>
//...
<head>
<title><?php echo CLocale::Instance()->getText("StrMemberArea")?></title>
```

Comment: Can't state it often enough: What did i think when not echoing at all?? Thanks, Philiüü

Answer (score 2):

To get anything displayed you no just need to return it, but also `echo` or `print` it. Like this:

```
<title><?php echo CLocale::Instance()->getText("StrMemberArea")?></title>
```